# Java: cannot execute binary file?

Tags: linux, java

I'm trying to install Java on my Linux machine, but I'm getting the following error upon executing the installer:

```
./install.sfx.5077: cannot execute binary file
```

I've tried to copy the Java folder from another machine, and I get the same error after executing the "java" binary.

What do you think could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, it appears that I downloaded 64bit version by mistake :/

Comment: Right, Unix binaries are not usually compatible across platforms. You should update your question with these details to make it useful to others and maybe close it.

Comment: ignore nik's comment, it's perfectly fine to answer your own question.  you can accept your answer after a couple of days.

Comment: Huh. I guess there is no `EBADARCH`, eh?

Comment: +1, and +1! I spent almost a half hour pounding my head against a keyboard until I ran across this and realized the server I was migrating to was 32 bit not 64 bit like my old server.